# Etymology of the name Wales/Welsh in modern English: which one is the basic term?

Tags: history

I am interested in the way the name of Wales (and of the Welsh) has been transliterated/translated in other languages.

(I have become interested in *that* because, as a native Romanian speaker I have noticed the abnormal translation of that name in Romanian — more on that [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34254/when-was-the-name-of-wales-first-mentioned-in-romanian-and-in-which-form). — I think that in some cases — the Romance languages, except Romanian, maybe Corsican too? — "Wales" has been translated by replacing W with G. I wonder if that is the case or not: whether the term Wales has been taken into account as such within the neo-Latin language and adapted to it, or was the G-version term first created in Latin? But that is **not** the question here, it would be a subject for a different question, a per-language SE question - not for this site).

All I am asking here is: ***what is the situation in English?***

I think I am familiar with the root-word: the Proto-Germanic word `walha` 'foreigner, stranger, Romance-speaker', brought by Anglo-Saxons to the British Isles. In **Old English**, the name of the country comes from the name of the people: `Wealana`/`Wealas` means "foreigners" and Wales (like Cornwall) derives from that (more [here](http://www.old-engli.sh/trivia.php?ID=Wales)).

What about the word `Welsh` in **Modern English**? Is it derived from the name of the country (`Wales`) (just like *Romanian* is derived from *Romania*) or directly from the name of the people in Old English (`Wealas`) (like *Romania* is derived from *român/roman*)?

---

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

What happens in Old English is clear to me. The term is an adjective (*foreigner*) that gives the name of the people and *then* of the country. But in modern English it seems to me that *Welsh comes from Wales* like "selfish" comes from "self", "girlish" from girl, and by the way Pol*ish* from Pole, Fren*ch* from France, Itali*an* from Italy, Romani*an* from Romania — that is: like it happens in most other (foreign) languages where the name of the Welsh is derived from the name of the country (transliterated from English).

Is that impression justified? If yes, that would be normal, many modern exonyms are created like that (Hungary > Hungari*an*, Wallachia > Wallachi*an*, Romania > Romani*an*); while the endonyms operate conversely: *magyar* > *Magyar**ország***; *valah > Valah**ia***, român* > *Român**ia***.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wales) has 'The English words "Wales" and "Welsh" derive from the same Old English root (singular Wealh, plural Wēalas), a descendant of Proto-Germanic *Walhaz,...' And have you tried The Online Etymology Dictionary?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - see edit please

Comment: Compare *Frankish*; there never was a place whose name in English could be the parent of this adjective.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - *Frankish* is a good example *chronologically*, **etymologically**: the name of the country comes *latest*, just like for Wales, but not "never":  in the end there was [Francia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francia), and then France, parents of the adjective, derived from the name of the people.  — I was just confused that the present English word *Welsh* is the same as name of the people and as adjective. That was not the case in the past though. The chronological diagram is what I needed.

Comment: @cipricus If *Frankish* were a synonym of *French*, you'd have a better point.  What language would derive *Frankish* from *Francia*? — um, I don't know where I'm going with this

Comment: @AntonSherwood - sorry that I didn't make myself clear: *Before the answer* I thought that the name of the people (Welsh) derived from that of the country (Wales) - like an exonym: *Romania* > *Romanian*. But in the past there was no country, while the people were there: *Wales* were the people (meant "the Welsh"), *Welsh* was the adjective (like in "a Welsh woman").  When the country was named, it took the name of the people (Wales), while they took as name the adjective (Welsh). **Name of people and adjective were separate words**: not now. Vaguely that is the case in *Pole* vs *Polish*.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - Also based on the answer I notice other errors in my question: I guess French doesn't come from France (no more than *françois* comes from *France* in French), but they evolved in tandem from older tandem.

Comment: @cipricus Why do you reckon *françois* is not derived from *France*? The suffix is now productive; was it not, back when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

**The term *Wales* initially referred to the people, with *Wales* as the name of the country coming from that later. *Welsh* (the present name of the people) comes from the old adjective describing individual members of  The Wales, rather than the present name of the country.**

```
 Volcae -> Walhaz (people) -> Wælas (people)     -> Wales (people)     -> Wales (country)
                           -> Wælisc (adjective) -> Welsh (adjective)  -> Welsh (people)
```

---

As you noted, the history of the term Welsh (people) comes from the Old English Wælas, from Proto-Germanic Walhaz, derived from the Roman name for these people - the Volcae (which was almost anybody living in the Western Roman Empire, who wasn't a Roman).

Note, the group-name for the people was the Wælas, and from the same root - comes the word to describe an individual as being part of that group - Wælisc. *(Similar to the group Celts, and individuals who are Celtic)*

---

However, during this time - there was no single country called "Wales" (or a variant of).

On the island of Great Britain, we had the people (also referred to by the same Volcae/Wælas/foreigner terms) who would be known as Britons (due to the actual place they were).

When the Anglo-Saxons arrived, the Britons were slowly pushed back towards Strathclyde, Cornwall and modern-day Wales. As such, the term Wælas was now applied to the peoples in these specific regions, contrasting to the Anglo-Saxon settlers on the rest of the island.

*(Note, each of these regions was still controlled by different groups, such as Strætcledwalas for the Wælas that lived around Strathclyde)*

In the 13th Century, the remaining parts of these regions were then taken over by a single ruler, and the title "Prince of Wales" was given by Henry III.

Note that this is "Prince of Wales" as in "Prince of [the] Wales (people)".

From here, with those regions under control of a single ruler, fitting into the larger system - the name "Wales" appears to understandably transition from "the Wales (people)" to "the name of that region that contains all of the Wales".

(Giving the country it's modern name "Wales").

At the same time as all of this, as mentioned at the start, the individual themselves were described as Wælisc (as was their language). This then turned into the more modern "Welsh" (e.g. "A Welsh person"), which is now used as the collective noun for the people as a whole (The Welsh).

---

*Note, as this is an English question - this answer does not mention the self-identified name Cymru, which was the name the 'Welsh' people have in their own language.*

Sources:
https://wordhistories.net/2016/07/28/wales-cymru/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wales#Etymology

Comment: `In the 13th Century, the remaining parts of these regions were then taken over by a single ruler, and the title "Prince of Wales" was given by Henry III. (Giving the country it's modern name "Wales").` Doesn't  that mean that *at the time* the term "Prince of Wales" meant "Prince of *the Welsh*", *Wales* meaning then *Welsh*?

Comment: Is the modern term of the country ("Wales") strictly referring to the land or has it ever meant the name of the people before naming the country? Is the formula "Prince of Wales" referring firstly to the land or to the people? - or is that impossible to tell?

Comment: @cipricus Correct, at that time "Prince of Wales" can be read correctly as "Prince of the Wales (people)"/"Prince of the Welsh". Tracing the first time people starting equating "that region which is now nicely tied away and contains the Wales (people)", with "Wales is the name of that region" seems near impossible - but that seems to be the transition.

Comment: `at that time "Prince of Wales" can be read correctly as "Prince of the Wales (people)"/"Prince of the Welsh"` — **that** is my answer! The people were called "the Wales" **first**, then was the country! Could you add that in bold letters to the answer? :) It is not the same as "they evolved in tandem". The tandem evolution was in Old English or Saxon maybe, while in modern Norman/English the name of the country is based on the name of the people.

Comment: @cipricus Excellent, done!

Comment: **In modern Norman/English the name of the country is based on the name of the people**

Comment: @cipricus Feel free to just click the Edit button directly and suggest changes - I'll approve anything that makes sense, if you feel it cleans up the answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101468/discussion-between-cipricus-and-bilkokuya).

Comment: `At the same time as all of this, as mentioned at the start, the individual themselves could be referred to as Wælisc (as could their language). This then turned into the more modern "Welsh"`. - From the conclusion we discussed it would result that before arriving to "Welsh",  "Wælisc" became "Wales". From Wales we have both the name and the country (as such) and of the people (Welsh).

Comment: @cipricus Welsh (Wælisc) did not transform into Wales; that part is simultaneous. The name of the country Wales comes from the collective name of the people Wales. I've added a diagram to clear it up.

Comment: That diagram is very very useful! Great!

Comment: Now I understand the distinction between name of the people and the adjectival use. Wales as name of the people had Welsh as adjective, and *that* led to the present name of the people, without disappearing itself though, as in present English the adjective (e.g. "Welsh sheep", "English breakfast") has the same form as the noun (*which doesn't seem to have been the case in Saxon/Old English*.)